# Открытие окна поверх родительского (windows.open)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы дочернее окно, которое создается с помощью windows.open, было всегда впереди родительского?

Т.е. даже если я буду нажимать на родительское окно,то дочернее все равно должно быть впереди.

Comment: причем тут теги windows и php????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Из соображений безопасности. Такие фокусы разрешаются внутри одного окна использованием `<div` с очень большим показателем z-index (заведомо большим, чем у всех остальных блоков).

Раньше было можно через принудительный возврат фокуса, сейчас его браузеры резонно игнорируют.

Comment: @kness , жаль...